# Skip first line uploading csv into mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I want to skip the first line of CSV(header part) while uploading it into MySQL using PHP but it always inserts the first line into MySQL table and it also does not upload total records in MySQL. I have 1000 records in my CSV but it uploads only 174 records at a time. I am using the below code to upload CSV into MySQL. Anyone has idea what I am doing wrong.

```
    <?php

include 'config.php';
$flag = true;
 if(isset($_POST["import"])){

        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];      


         if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
         {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {

 if($flag)
  {
   $flag = false;
    continue;
     }
               $sql = "INSERT into tbl_customer(customer_name,customer_excise_code,city) 
                   values ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."')";

                   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if(!isset($result))
                {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                            window.location = \"index.php\"
                          </script>";       
                }
                else {
                      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                        window.location = \"index2.php\"
                    </script>";
                }
             }

             fclose($file); 
         }
    }    


 ?>
```

Comment: MySQL’s LOAD DATA INFILE statements can import CSV files with great speeds and from a starting line

Answer (score 0):

You may try with next suggestions:

- check for empty lines in your file before `if($flag) {...}`
- your check with `isset()` will always return true, because [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns boolean or object, so you don't know if the statement is executed correctly. You execute `INSERT` statement and in this case the expected result from `mysqli_query()` will be boolean, so just check `$result`.

PHP:

```
<?php
$flag = true;
...

while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if (is_null($getData[0])) {
        continue;
    }
    if ($flag) {
        $flag = false;
        continue;
    }
    ...

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (!$result) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }   

    ...
}

...
?>
```